# Optimisation: Calculate at each step or calculate all at the end?

Tags: c#, optimization, vectorization

I do a lot of calculations and **in the middle of that**, I get a result, call it X.

I have some variables that are associated with X:

**X_sum** : total so far

**X_sumOfSquares** : as the name suggests; sum of (X*X) every time X is produced, so sum of X^2 basically.

N : Number of times the operation that calculates X has been called

At the end I use these figures to calculate the confidence range where the true mean of X should lie, based on the mean of the sample I have.

Regardless of what I'm trying to achieve, my question is:

**Assuming I calculate X 1000 times, so N = 1000. Which method is faster:**

1. Update x_sum and x_sumOfSquares every time I have X.
2. Create array of size 1000 in the beginning, store all values of X in that array. At the end go through the array and calculate x_sum  and x_sumOfSquares.

For the second method, there really should be a way to vectorise this method, there are ways to do this in C++, for example I remember Intel C++ had some automatic vectorisation of such simple cases, but I don't know how to do that in C#.

Comment: It sounds as though it would take 10 minutes or so to write both cases and find the answer out for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

First method is faster than naive iteration, as you will not need to iterate on X vector at the end of the process.

It is also cheaper regarding memory usage if you only needed the X values vector for your stats computations.

You can also contemplate to use Linq methods to compute Sum/Mean/Count (Linq queries are run in parallel)
    Sum : Sum()
    N : Count()
    Std : Aggregate()